# ResultSet Column Count in FMDB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

is there any way we can get the column count from an FMResultSet row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FMResultSet implements following function:

```
- (int)columnCount;
```

However, I can barely think of any scenario where you are not aware of the column count of your query. Please do not use `SELECT *` (except debugging).

Comment: `-columnCount` can be very useful (for example) if you're writing an app to browse any SQLite database.  In that case, you want your selection and extraction to do a `SELECT *` and be able to handle any table schema.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thank you for pointing this out. I wanted to make this statement because the `SELECT *` is very often misused.

Comment: I must apologize for my hash answer: FMResultSet is even implementing  `-(NSDictionary *)resultDict;` making it theoretically possible to iterate over a result set.

Comment: I agree that it often returns a lot more information than you probably need, and selecting less can be a great way to enhance performance.  But sometimes there are valid reasons for wanting everything. :)  (+1 for a correct answer, btw)